# How to pass some data from one function to another in same controller ? -Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function chat($team1,$team2){
    $id1=$team1;
    $id2=$team2;
    return view('chat') ;
}


public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
     $user = Auth::user();
     $message = $user->messages()->create([
          'message' => $request->input('message'),
          'first_team_id'=>$id1<to call here
          'second_team_id'=>$id2<to call here
     ]);
}
```

I want this $id1 and $id2 from chat function to send into sendMessage.This function in same controller !

```
Route::get('/directchat/{team1}/{team2}',['as'=>'chat.start','uses'=>'ChatsController@chat']);

Route::post('messages', 'ChatsController@sendMessage');
```

Comment: If you are calling your send message from the chat view, then you can pass the IDs to your chat view and from the chat view you pass them to the `sendMessage` as request params

Comment: Do you want to send those inside controller or throw request or throw view?

Comment: Yes , i am calling sendMessage from chat view but this form is under vue.js and i dont know how to pass data in vue so is it possible to send data from function to function ? Thanks for answer...

Comment: Is it possible to throw view and send data to another function ?

Answer (score 0):

chat.blade.php:

```
<div>
    Your chat view code
    <form action="/messages" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="team1" value="{{ $team1 }}">
          <input type="hidden" name="team2" value="{{ $team2 }}">
          <input type="submit" value="Send Message Link">
    </form>
</div>
```

Your controller will look like

```
public function chat($team1,$team2){
    return view('chat' ,["team1"=>$team1,"team2"=>$team2]) ;
}


public function sendMessage(Request $request)
{
     $user = Auth::user();
     $message = $user->messages()->create([
          'message' => $request->input('message'),
          'first_team_id'=> request('team1'),
          'second_team_id'=> request('team1')
     ]);
}
```

Comment: This is my chat.blade.php

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Chats</div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <chat-messages :messages="messages"></chat-messages>
 </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                <chat-form
                   v-on:messagesent="addMessage"
                  :user="{{ Auth::user() }}"

 ></chat-form></div>
 </div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>

Comment: This is under vue.js so i dont have a form !

Comment: in some vue.js files but i dont understand how vue works...so i need another solution to solve problem...

Comment: my friend the only way around this is to pass the team IDs via the post data when the `POST /messages` endpoint is called, you cannot set variables in the controller because these cannot be static. So if you cannot do it in the way I described above, you have to find the endpoint call in vue.js , or else you have to change the library to something you can understand